# how can i use Entity Framework 4.1 in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, visual-studio-2012

I have a web application on a web farm and i use .NET 4 and entity data model 4.1.

when i started working on this web application i used visual studio 2010, and today i have uninstalled it and installed new version (Visual Studio 2012).

Due to some reasons, i have deleted my ado.net entity data model to recreate it, but i
pay attention that visual studio 2012 use `entity framework 5` not 4.1. I have updated it but in old model i can context constructor to change my connection string but in this new model have no constructor, is that true?

I have installed `EF 4.1` but it doesn't works and I've added version 5 to my project.
Background info: my web application is on a shared host and i can not update it to EF 5.

How can i use entity framework 4.1 in visual studio 2012 ?
is that possible? if yes, how?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have installed EF 4.1 but it doesn't work"? Have you removed the reference to ef 5 in your project and tried adding ef 4.1 back as a reference?

Comment: in vs when you add entity model to your project it add model files and structure by itself,it has no relating to entity dll or reference

Comment: I do not understand your response, but the answer you selected is exactly what I suggested.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Remove Existing (Entity framework 5)

1. Remove the existing reference (to Entity framework 5) under the References section in your Project in Solution explorer.
2. Remove the corresponding entry from your ***packages.config*** file. If you open the packages.config file, you will see an xml structure and you will see an element with id `EntityFramework` with `version` attribute value as `5.0.0`. Remove that line( that package element).

### Add Again (Entity framework 4.1)

Now go to the package manager window(**View->Other Windows -> Package Manager Console**) and execute the following command there.

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 4.1.10331.0
```

This will download EF 4.1 to your project and you will see the success message like below.

[image]

Reference : http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/4.1.10331.0

Always keep in mind that there are a lot of improvements made in EF 5. So consider to consume all those as possible as you can.

Comment: I don't have a packages.config file. And I can't seem to remove the Entity Framework reference. It doesn't appear anywhere when I look through the references