# How to use older version of Entity Framework when updating Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, edmx

I am working on a Web application which uses **Entity Framework 4.1.10331.0**.

I have made couple of changes in DB and now I need to update the model (Entity Model/EDMX) in Visual Studio, but when I update I get this screen which allows main to choose between **EF5** and **EF6** with a message that *"Your project references an older version of entity framework ......"*

How can I use **EF 4.1.10331.0** while updating (or even creating new) the model ?

Upgrading to **EF5** or **EF6** is not an option at the moment because I will have to make many changes if I upgrade. I just want that my model will be updated/created using **EF 4.1.10331.0**

Thanks in advance

[image: Your project references an older version of entity framework]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can i use Entity Framework 4.1 in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030416/how-can-i-use-entity-framework-4-1-in-visual-studio-2012)

Comment: @Jawad I already have tried this. It says "EntityFramework 4.1.10331.0 is alredady installed". Also, there is no reference to EF 5. My projects having reference to 4.1.10331.0 and packages.config having entry for 4.1.10331.0. Still I don't get option for 4.1.10331.0 when I try to update/created Entity model.

Comment: Use an old Visual Studio too? *because I will have to make many changes if I upgrade* - oof, I think you should bite the bullet and update to a version of EF that *was* released in the last decade.. I've never looked at EF that old, but if it's like the other frameworks I was using at a similar age (Mindscape Lightspeed) the edmx is probably just some XML file you can manually patch with your new columns, patch your entities and all will be rosy..

Comment: Yes, EDMX is just an XML file, and your .cs files are generated from that.  So as an alternative to upgrading EF or downgrading VS, you can generate a new EDMX file in a separate project and manually compare and patch your existing EDMX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per directions of Caius Jard and Daid Browne, I manually updated the Edmx (Xml) and it worked perfectly.
i.e.
In such case the best solution if to edit Edmx file's Xml manually.