# I want to suggest version error. I am using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using free vs. I want to use Entity Framework 4. But whenever I build it, it is version 6. Upgrades with build. When I want to build, I am using web app. I want to use Entity Framework v4.3.1..

Please help me.

Comment: Hi Onur, it sounds like you're having an old reference to EF6 lingering somewhere. Have a look in your csproj or packages.json files (depending on your project). Additionally you might have another dependency depending on EF6 which pulls your runtime to that version. It's hard to say with the info you're providing.

Comment: Where are all the EF4 buses coming from all of a sudden ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70189436/how-to-use-older-version-of-entity-framework-when-updating-model#comment124076428_70189436

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check in Visual Studio is to right click on the Solution item in Solution explorer and select "Manage Nuget packages for solution". From there, make sure "Installed" is selected (Not Browse) and search for "EntityFramework by Microsoft" and select that. In the right hand side there should be a list of projects with an "Installed:  ###" and a "Version: 6.2.0".  If your "Installed:" value says "6.2.0" or "Multiple versions installed", then look through the list of projects, select any that have "6.2.0" and then go to "Version: " and select the desired version (I.e. 4.3.1) or the version that matches the rest of the assemblies.  Hit "Install" to update the selected references back to the desired version.

You may need to manually check things like app.config / web.config for version overrides that might try to replace older references back up to 6.0.0 etc. The package manager *usually* does a decent job of updating references, but it's not always 100% reliable.

If there are no projects in the solution referencing EF6 then this can also occur when you add a reference that has a dependency on a newer version of EF. If you added a reference to something that needs EF6 you don't really have a choice but to find/rebuild that dependency with the older EF reference, or bring the rest of your projects up to EF6. There are possibly ways to manage multiple version references at runtime, provided things like entities etc. don't cross between assemblies using EF4 and those using EF6.

I would highly recommend upgrading from EF4 to EF6 as EF6 has considerably better performance than EF4.